# How to get a PIC12F1822 running at 32MHz

Tags: pic, oscillator, microchip

I just can't get my PIC12F1822 to switch to 32MHz (8MHz + 4xPLL)
I am telling OSCCON to switch to 8MHz, but, according to the debugger, that value is never loaded into it! I also wait for the High Speed oscillator to be ready, but that bit is never set in OSCSTAT.

Here are the relevant snippets of my code.

```
__CONFIG _CONFIG1, _FOSC_INTOSC & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF & _CP_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _BOREN_OFF & _CLKOUTEN_OFF & _IESO_OFF & _FCMEN_OFF
__CONFIG _CONFIG2, _WRT_OFF & _PLLEN_ON & _STVREN_OFF & _BORV_19 & _LVP_OFF

; > SNIP <

START
    BANKSEL OSCCON
    movlw 0b11110000
    movwf OSCCON

    BANKSEL OSCSTAT
WaitOsc
    btfss OSCSTAT, 4
    goto WaitOsc

; execution never reaches here
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you poll for bit 6 of OSCSTAT - the PLLReady bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the answer, and I feel stupid.
Turns out that, while in MPLAB C you can write 0b11110000, in MPLAB ASM, you have to write B'11110000'.  But the assembler wasn't warning me about this.

Comment: Ahhh, of course, thanks for letting us know. I wouldn't feel silly, I think that's an easy mistake to make if you have been using C a lot, especially if no warning turns up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with that chip, but I do note that in order to get more than 16 MHz then VDD must be greater or equal to 2.5v.

Comment: It's running at 5v.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Vdd stable? Have you got bypass caps from Vdd to Vss?
Does the chip behave normally with a test program? (e.g. toggle pin)  .
The reason I ask is that if the oscillator never reaches stability then it is very likely something quite fundamental such as power supply problems.